# having trouble accessing MySql database by power bi use unable to connect we encountered a error?

Tags: .net, powerbi

While trying to access the database from POWER BI to MYSQL getting a error as

[image: 1]

UNABLE TO CONNECT

> we encountered a error while trying toconnect
> Details: "An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070542)'

Comment: From the looks of things this is an internal error so you should contact Microsoft support - but please tell us where PowerBI is running? Is this an on-prem MySQL instance, an Azure-hosted instance, or in a third-party datacenter? How have you set-up the MySQL connection? (Also, I don't believe MySQL supports NT security natively for logins, so I'm curious why PowerBI is attempting to use Win32 security impersonation)

Answer (score 0):

In the data source setting, can you remove the existing SQL server source connection and try again?
You can set permission when creating the data source.